# Proving $\sum_{k\geq0}\frac1{2^k}\sum_{l\geq0}\frac1{3^l}\sum_{m\geq0}\frac1{5^m}\cdots=\sum_{k,l,m,n,\ldots\geq0}\frac1{2^k3^l5^m7^n\cdots}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

May someone please help me to prove this formula or give me some hint to prove it?

$$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot\sum_{l\geq 0}\frac{1}{3^l}\cdot\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{5^m}\cdot\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{7^n}\cdots=\sum_{k,l,m,n,\ldots \geq 0}\frac{1}{2^k3^l5^m7^n\cdots}$$

Comment: Tonelli's Theorem.

Comment: Write the equation for finite sums and take limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \sum_{l=0}^{L} \frac{1}{3^l}  \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{M} \frac{1}{5^m} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{K} \frac{1}{7^k} = \sum_{n=l=m=k=0}^{n=N, l=L, m=M, k=K }\frac{1}{2^n3^l5^m7^k}.$$Now we can take limit both sides. The limit of the right side is the sumpremum of the corresponding sequence beacuse it is monotone. On the left side, we can split limit beacuse $n, l, m,$ and $k$ are independent. Then we have the desired equality.